# change UI background color using button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to change the background color of my UI using a button that is in a separate class and function. (like a light and dark mode)i can't see to get it to work. any ideas?

Comment: You can look into `tkinter.ttk` that implements themes for `tkinter` widgets

Answer (score 0):

Hi @ColinCactus and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have implemented light and dark themes for my projects. The best way to do it is as follows:

1.Add a `Button` to the window for toggling between the 2 modes. Sample code:

```
x = 0    
b1=Button(root, text="Light Mode/Dark Mode", command=function_here)
```

2.In the command option of the button, type in the following code:

```
def function_here():


    if x == 0:
        x=1
        #Code for light mode

    else:
        x=0
        #Code for dark mode
```

3. In the places of #Code for light mode and #Code for dark mode, replace it with changing you widget's background and foreground colors.

That's it! I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please fix the code indentation and use better variable names not `x`/`function_here`?

Comment: Why? What's the matter?

Comment: It is hard for new programmers to understand what the variable `x` does. The variable name should always give a hint to its purpose and type. You should always choose appropriate variable names like: `using_light_mode`.